# How to clear all notifications from Notification Tray in android

Tags: android

is there any way to clear notifications from Notification Tray all(including third party applications also).

how can i achieve this functionality can u please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What code have you tried do far?

Comment: I want to clear (including 3rd party applications) all notifications from Notification Tray.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Removing).

- The user clicks the notification, and you called setAutoCancel() when
  you created the notification.
- You call cancel() for a specific
  notification ID. This method also deletes ongoing notifications.
- You
  call cancelAll(), which removes all of the notifications you
  previously issued.

**Note:** You can't cancel notifications from other apps - its done that way to prevent malicious apps from hiding other applications.

Comment: Thank you for the replay but i want to clear all notifications including 3rd party applications also from notification tray.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: @flex what is not possible ? Please mention here.